# Is there a way to combine a letter from one cell with a word from another cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet with 1600 rows of data. I need to create usernames from the first and last names of everyone in the list. I can manually go through and get the first letter of their first name and combine it with the last name to create one, but I am wondering if there is a way to automate it in Excel. I tried concatenate but it appears to be all or none as far as combining values goes. I am hoping there is someone that knows how to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can nest functions in Excel, so try this, if the first name is in column A and the last name in column B:

```
=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1,1),B1)
```

The "LEFT" function gives you a certain number of characters from the left side of the cell you specify.

Comment: Jenn, thank you so much. You saved me a ton of time.

Comment: the same thing as CONCATENATE is to write the formula                                         =LEFT(A1,1)&B1

Comment: @datatoo -- cool! I didn't know about the ampersand operator. That'll save me some typing in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest adding the "TRIM()" function to Jenn's answer to prevent unwanted spaces in your username, also just use the "&" instead of CONCATENATE
=left(trim(A1),1) & trim(B1)

Comment: Agree on the trim(); nothing wrong with being tidy. Make sure you do it around just the B1, though, not around the whole function; otherwise you could still end up with a space from in front of the first name.